# Script for changing text encoding in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, scripting, encoding, xcode4

I have a set of .txt files saved in ISO Latin 1.
Before I put them in my application I have to convert them to UTF-8

Is it possible to create a script for this task in Xcode 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a shell script build phase that invokes `iconv`. Your 'from' encoding would be `CSISOLATIN1` and your 'to' encoding would be `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I made a shell script and it works very well :

```
/bin/sh

TXTPATH="${SRCROOT}/assets/Pages"
TXT_EXT='*.txt'

for f in $(find $TXTPATH -name $TXT_EXT); do
   iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$f" > "${f%.*}.utf8"
done
```